# How to scan DPDK project as

Tags: compilation, coverity

I'm a Coverity user, and I want to scan the DPDK project as below.
(https://scan.coverity.com/projects/dpdk-data-plane-development-kit)

I did a scan on a DPDK project, which is able to build with build command as below,
"make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc && make T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc ".
Then I got " No files were emitted to analyze"!  (( --gcc is configured !))
After a discussion with Official Support, he recommended here to us.
Because there's high probability that Make command calls another build tool, or run gcc compile command with container.

So we want to know if we could learn how DPDK build project.
Does DPDK uses docker?
We already have a environment could build DPDK project.
What is the cov-build command I can uses?

Thanks,
BR,

Hardy

Comment: based on the commands shared for build looks like you are using DPDK 19.11.6 LTS or lower. can you please confirm by checking on your machine if make has build the libraries in appropriate folder. If yes, then it has to do with some settings in coverity not able to find the built files.

Comment: are there any updates.